# HttpMetadataProvider replacement in opensaml 3

Tags: java, opensaml

We were using opensaml2.6.5 along with commons-httpclient3.1. However, there is critical vulnerability in commons-httpclient and it is suggested to upgrade to httpclient4.5.13. This version has lot of changes including `HttpClient` class. Earlier this was in `org.apache.commons.httpclient` package. Now it is in `org.apache.http.client` package.

In opensaml2.6.5, there are classes which uses older version of HttpClient. So, after upgrade, few classes cannot accept new class as input parameter. Couple of opensaml classes that has problem are `org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider` and `org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FileBackedHTTPMetadataProvider`.
What is the replacement for these classes in Opensaml 3?

Answer (score 0):

In OpenSAML 3 and 4 these are replaced by `org.opensaml.saml.metadata.resolver.impl.HTTPMetadataResolver` and `org.opensaml.saml.metadata.resolver.impl.FileBackedHTTPMetadataResolver`

It is not always easy to used the resolvers in the new API. Here are some good examples for using metadata and credential resolvers.
[Signing and verifying signatures with OpenSAML 4](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/2012/11/verifying-signatures-with-opensaml.html)